# How can I move a container inside of another container in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am a very beginner in bootstrap and i am trying to move a container to the left in another container but it doesn't work.

[In this photo i am trying to make the div which has a checkbox in it move to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5eMp.png)

I tried to define a "ml-0" class to inner container but it didn't work.What is the problem with my code ?

```
    <div id="prog-lang-selection-row-1" class="container-fluid">

        <div id="desktop-development-div" class="container ml-0">

            <input type="checkbox" name="desk-development-checkbox" id="desk-development-checkbox">
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: give us the picture or somewhat similar to the result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I shared the photo.

Answer (score 1):

Try float in css.

```
<style>
#desktop-development-div{
  float:right;
}
<style>
```

**Make sure parent container is full width or display block**

It might help you

Answer (score 0):

Remove class ml-0 and add class ms-0. This will set margin-left to 0. Like this

```
<div id="desktop-development-div" class="container ms-0">

    <input type="checkbox" name="desk-development-checkbox" id="desk-development-checkbox">
</div>
```